# Penthouse settings for mobile optimization

Tags: css, gulp

I installed Penthouse to generate critical CSS.
I use gulp and my settings are:

```
gulp.task('penthouse', ['sass'], function () {
    penthouse({
    ...
    width: 1300,                    // viewport width
    height: 500,                    // viewport height
    ...
```

When I run it and test with PageSpeed, I get a really nice improvement for Desktop but I still get "Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content" for the critical css file for mobile.

I am guessing that Penthouse reads the site as a desktop browser looking for elements within the viewport. Since my site is responsive, I suppose it will not see the elements on mobile.

Is there a way to generate a different file for mobile?

I saw some mention of this setting:

```
...
dimensions: [{
        height: 200,
        width: 500
    }, {
        height: 900,
        width: 1200
    }]
...
```

What's the best approach here?